# ReactJs Show state value in TextInput

Tags: reactjs, state

I am working on a form where the user must fill many fields.
Some of those fields have data that comes from entities, so I created a search component where the user clicks on a button, a grid of the entity opens and when selecting I return the selected row as a prop and save in states the values. (this works ok)

Those values that are stored in States, to be shown in diferents TextInput (react-admin)

```
import React, {useState, useCallback} from "react";
import {Edit, TextInput, SimpleForm} from 'react-admin';
import ProcesoSearchButton from "../proceso/ProcesoBusquedaBtn"

const ProcesoEdit = props => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});
    const classes = useStyles();

    const {
        idProceso = '', proceso = '', d_proceso = '',
    } = state;
    
    
        const updateProceso = useCallback(async (who) => {
        setState(state => ({
            ...state,
            idProceso: who.id,
            proceso: who.proceso,
            d_proceso: who.d_proceso,
        }));
    })

    return (
        <Edit {...props} title={<ProcesoStdTitle/>}>
            <SimpleForm>
            <TextInput source="proceso" label={"N°Proceso"} 
                            defaulValue={proceso} 
                           fullWidth={true}
                           formClassName={classes.proceso} inputProps={{readOnly: true,}} variant="filled"/>

            <TextInput source="d_proceso" label={"Descripción"}  fullWidth={true}
                            defaulValue ={d_proceso}
                           formClassName={classes.d_proceso} inputProps={{readOnly: true,}}
                           variant="filled"/>

            <ProcesoSearchButton callbackProceso={updateProceso} formClassName={classes.btnBusqueda}/>
           
           ....
           
           </SimpleForm>
        </Edit>
    )
};
export default ProcesoEdit;
```

With the previously detailed code it works in a first search, States are updated and shown in the TextFields. But if i do a second search, the States are updated but not the displayed value in TextFields.
If I use the value prop it doesn't work.
How can I solve that? I am trying to keep using react-admin because it's what I use throughout the app. This code using MUI TextField works, but it would not be ideal. Thanks

Comment: I think your problems are caused by using "defaultValue" instead of "value". defaultValue is not meant to cause re-renders of components (https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#default-values). Use value instead on your TextInputs and I think you should be fine.

Comment: I tryed using "value". But it doesn't re-render when state value is updated. At least not the way I'm doing it.

Comment: I partially succeeded using Format, in this way the value is updated. But it does not load the source value when I enter edit mode nor does it save the new value when pressing the update button...

format={formatproceso}

    const formatproceso = v => {
        return proceso
    };